# God never met him

Tags: riddle, word

> God never met him,
>
> But sometimes kings did.
>
> People like you and I always meet him,
>
> And the mathematicians love him.

Who/what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old question along these lines whose answer is

> an equal

and I think this is probably what you have in mind. (I think it may also be what Hilal meant by his answer, with "colleague" presumably being a not-very-good translation from another language.)

The explanations are all pretty obvious, but here they are:

> God by definition has no equal. Kings do (e.g., other kings) and frequently meet them. Ordinary people certainly do and meet them all the time. And equality is a really important concept in mathematics.

Comment: That is what I had in mind, indeed. Good job!

Comment: I was sure I'd seen something very similar on p.s.c before but now can't find it. (Perhaps I was thinking of the "it is greater than God" one whose answer is "nothing", which has certainly been here.)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> sin?

Mathematicians love him.

> sin as mathematical formula

God never met him,

> God does not accept such things as sins, he forgivess all we do

But sometimes kings did.

> Dont know about this one.. maybe Kings threw you into jail / killed you for your sins

People like you and I always meet him,

> People tend to lie a lot which could be considered a sin

And the mathematicians love him.

> same as first line

Comment: That's incorrect!

Comment: @IAmInPLS I guess I'll try to think of something else than ;) But I was so proud of me because I thought that my answer would fit (almost) all your clues ;)

Comment: It fits pretty well actually, except for the "king" line! But yes, the idea is to find a word having a double meaning ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Pi or Pie

Explanation

Mathematicians love him.

> Mathematicians use Pi in calculations

God never met him,

> Pie was human made and was not exist from the beginning.

But sometimes kings did.

> Evidence were found that Pie was found in Egypt at the time of pharaohs located in the Valley of the Kings.

People like you and I always meet him,

> We all love to eat pi

And the mathematicians love him.

> Pi helps mathematicians solve many calculations and equations.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. The first line was not supposed to be here. Anyway, that doesn't change the fact that your answer is not correct :) (explanation about god and about people like you and I are not convincing)

Answer (score 0):

I know it. Is it "colleague" ??

> God never met him,

For my country there is one God So he can't meet a colleague.
(PS:please read my comment . This riddle is [a little common](http://www.bilmecelerimiz.com/soforun-hergun-gordugucobanin-ara-sira-gordugu-ama-allahin-hic-goremedigi-bisey-bilmecesi-1655.html#.V5ILaeiLSUk) in my country so I immediately answered with thinking I found the answer.But this result depends on from person to person)

> But sometimes kings did.

A king can meet another king, because in other countries there may be a king.

> People like you and I always meet him,

As my friend asked that question and we are not so special person who has not so specific job that other peoples can't have, we can always meet him.

> And the mathematicians love him.

Thought mathematicians like discussing about Math when they meet with their colleague, so they like each other.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. Can you elaborate your answer? Maybe by matching the word you are proposing to the lines of the question. Anyway, that is not correct.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Puzzling.SE. Site policy is to add an explanation as to why you think that your answer is correct. Why don't you [edit] it?

Comment: Thanks @IAmInPLS. Sorry, this riddle is a little common in my country, like, if you google you can find the answer easly so I thought you meaned that riddle and so excited and answered immediately :) But now when I think my answer depends on from person to person.

Comment: I am writing in a minute, the riddle I mentioned is not exactly same as yours but they are so similar so now I am writing explanation which fits yours. Sorry for late